# Visual Studio seems to be using a different dns than my machine

Tags: c#, web, dns

I try to download the source code of a webpage. This web page is for watching TV shows, and is blocked by my isp.

On my PC (Windows 10), I set the dns server to cloudflare's dns so I can watch in peace.

When running my code to download the page content, I get the "site blocked" page, not the webpage I get when using any browser.

Can you please explain to me why that is?

This is the code I'm running:

```
async Task download(string _url, List<string> _list = null)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(_url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            { 
                Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();

                string fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                string filePath = workingDirectory + @"\" + _id.ToString() + ".html";

                File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContent);

                if (_list != null)
                {
                    _list.Add(filePath);
                }

                log($"downloaded \"{_url}\"");
            }
            else
            {
                log($"download failed for \"{_url}\" \r\n status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log($"error downloading \"{_url}\" \r\n message: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this with the same result:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    string sourceCode = client.DownloadString("URL");
    Console.WriteLine(htmlCode);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a DNS issue?  It seems more likely to me that the site is blocking the user agent that you are using.

Comment: I used similar code a while ago on the site and it was working fine.
Tried it now again to test it with the same result. I was on a different network back then.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with HTTP traces for both "working" (presumably from browser) and "not working" (from your app) versions - use HTTP debugger like Fiddler to capture. There is a chance you could compare response yourself... but if you could not detect differences someone else may. If you want more info on general HTTP debugging/proxying my favorite podcast just posted one for you :) - https://syntax.fm/show/668/hacking-the-tonal-proxying-intercepting-debugging-traffic

Comment: The site may have also changed their rules about what it's blocking since the last time you tested this code